# Is the filter executed first then the validator in the Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

If I had this code

```
$field = new Zend_Form_Element();
$field->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Alnum());
$field->setFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringToLower());
```

is the check for only alphanumeric characters executed after the string has been transformed to lower case?

Comment: setFilter doesn't exist. The correct method is addFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zend/Form/Element.php, method isValid:

```
    $this->setValue($value);
    $value = $this->getValue();
```

`getValue` call the filters on the data, before the value is passed to the validators. So yes, the value is filtered before validation. You can test it with:

```
$field = new Zend_Form_Element('test');
$field->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Alnum());

// Display bool(false)
var_dump($field->isValid('A,B'));

$field->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_Alnum());

// Display bool(true)
var_dump($field->isValid('A,B'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The filter is activated by the element's `getValue()` method.